# Select column where another related column's total is 0

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called `xDays` set up like below:

```
╔══════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═══════╗
║ Project_Name ║          Date           ║ Hours ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═══════╣
║ proj1        ║ 2010-03-03 00:00:00.000 ║     0 ║
║ proj1        ║ 2010-03-04 00:00:00.000 ║     0 ║
║ proj1        ║ 2010-03-05 00:00:00.000 ║     0 ║
║ proj2        ║ 2010-03-03 00:00:00.000 ║     1 ║
║ proj2        ║ 2010-03-04 00:00:00.000 ║     0 ║
║ proj2        ║ 2010-03-05 00:00:00.000 ║     0 ║
╚══════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═══════╝
```

What I'm trying to do is select each `Project_Name` who's total in the `Hours` column is `0`. In the above example, the select statement should return `proj1`, since the total `hours` for it is 0, whereas the total hours for `proj2` is 1.

The closest I got was:

```
select sum(hours) as 'total', project_name
From xDays
group by project_name
order by project_name
```

This gives me a table showing the total hours for each project_name which DOES show `0` total hours for certain project_names. From here, I've tried a few different things and either get a

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to datatype int

error or empty results. Some examples of what I've tried:

```
 select sum(hours) as 'total', project_name
 From xDays
 where 'total' = convert(varchar(10), 0)
 group by project_name
 order by project_name`
```

This returns empty results.

```
select sum(hours) as 'total', project_name
From xDays
where 'total' = 0
group by project_name
order by project_name
```

This returns a conversion error (cannot convert varchar total to int).

How can I get this working properly?

Comment: Do all projects have entries in the `xDays` table / if they don't should the appear in the extract?  Is it possible to have negative hours assigned to a project?

Comment: No negative hours.

Comment: NB: `where 'total' = 0` here you're comparing the string value `total` (not the column / result) with 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter aggregate results with the [HAVING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx) clause:

```
select sum(hours) as 'total'
From xDays
group by project_name
HAVING sum(hours) = 0
order by project_name
```

The `HAVING` clause can only appear after the `GROUP BY` clause and can't use any column alias

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
Select Project_Name
 From  xDays
 Group By Project_Name
 Having Sum(Hours)=0
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all projects you want to report on are in the xDays table, [@PanagiotisKanavos's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40912285/361842)'s best.

**Special Scenarios / Considerations**

If it's possible to have projects which don't have any entries in the `xDays` table, but you still want those returned (i.e. since by not being in that table it's implied that no hours were spent on them).

```
select project_name
from Projects
where project_name not in
(
    select distinct project_name
    from xDays
    where xdays.hours != 0
)
```

If it's possible to have negative hours, and you want those projects where the total hours on that project equals zero (i.e. where negatives cancel positives):

```
select project_name
from Projects
where project_name not in
(
    select project_name
    from xDays
    group by project_name
    having sum(xdays.hours) != 0
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I actually had a separate select statement for projects that didn't have entries in the xDays table, but can combine them using your first statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select project_name
from xDays
group by project_name
having sum(xdays.hours) = 0
```

You will need to utilize tha `having` clause to filter based on an aggregate total