# Return max(date) based on total of another column

Tags: sql-server

Note: this is related to my other question here, [Select column where another related column's total is 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40912206/2480598)

I have a table called xDays set up like below:

```
╔══════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═══════╗
║ Project_Name ║          Date           ║ Hours ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═══════╣
║ proj1        ║ 2015-03-06 00:00:00.000 ║     2 ║
║ proj1        ║ 2015-03-05 00:00:00.000 ║     3 ║
║ proj1        ║ 2015-03-04 00:00:00.000 ║     0 ║
║ proj2        ║ 2016-03-03 00:00:00.000 ║     1 ║
║ proj2        ║ 2016-03-04 00:00:00.000 ║     0 ║
║ proj2        ║ 2016-03-05 00:00:00.000 ║     0 ║
╚══════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═══════╝
```

For each `Project_Name` that has a total of `Hours` GREATER than `0`, I want to return only the last `Date` entry for that project IF it's greater than a year ago and IF it's more than 0 hours.

In the above table, the select statement would return `proj1 | 2015-03-03 00:00:00.000` since it's total hours are > 0 (5 in this case), it is the most recent Date with > 0 hours, and it happened more than a year ago.

Right now I have:

```
select max(day), project_name
from xDays
where hours > 0
group by project_name, hours
having max(day) < dateadd(dd, -365, getdate())
order by project_name
```

This succeeds in giving me the dates > a year ago and > 0 hours, but it doesn't give just the latest one.

For the above example, it would give

```
2015-03-06 00:00:00.000 | proj1
2015-03-05 00:00:00.000 | proj1
```

I thought using `max(day)` would NOT return multiple dates for the same project?

Comment: You're grouping it by the `hours` in addition to the `project_name`.  Remove `hours` from the `group by`.

Comment: Yup that worked! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

When you have multiple "group by" fields, it groups on the combination of each. Since you are grouping by project_name AND hours, whenever either is different, it forms a separate group. The two rows you are seeing have different "hours" values.

So, as expressed in a comment above, just remove the hours field from the group by clause if you want only one row.

Comment: Perfect, it works now, thank you. Did not know that it forms a separate group each time. Still trying to learn all of this!